# XOR Hebbian test/example neural network

Tags: testing, machine-learning, neural-network, reinforcement-learning

I just finished writing some code that runs a hebbian learning feedforward neural network. I've done a backpropagation neural network before and the first thing I did to make sure it worked was too try the XOR problem.

What should I do to test my hebbian learning neural network?

Is there a hebbian way to learn XOR or some other problem a long the lines of "Hello World" for a neural network?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can use XOR problem once again. take a look at [this](http://www.ent.mrt.ac.lk/~ekulasek/ami/PartB.pdf)